# Power automate - Send email reminder on a working day

Tags: power-automate, flow, date, send-email

I have a SharePoint list where I need to send a reminder email 1 day before the due date. I have a scheduled flow that runs from Monday to Friday so that the email only gets sent on work days. My problem now is, if the item due date falls on a Monday, it will not send the email reminder because 1 day before that is a Sunday.

Here is the expression that I'm using:

```
formatDateTime(addDays(items('Apply_to_each')?['Acknowledgement_x0020_Due_x0020_'],-1),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Will it be possible to incorporate in the above expression that if the due date is a Monday, send the reminder email the Friday before? Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the expression within an `IF` function.

If today is **Friday**, subtract due date by **3 days**
, else subtract due date by **1 day**

```
if(equals(dayOfWeek(utcNow()),5)
        , formatDateTime(addDays(items('Apply_to_each')?['Acknowledgement_x0020_Due_x0020_'],-3),'yyyy-MM-dd')
        , formatDateTime(addDays(items('Apply_to_each')?['Acknowledgement_x0020_Due_x0020_'],-1),'yyyy-MM-dd')
    )
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks so much thebernardlim ☺